# SQL minimum date value after today's date Now()

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am writing a query and am having trouble filtering data as I would like.  In the table, there is a date field and an ItemCode field. I would like to return one record per ItemCode with the earliest date that is after today.

If today is 6/6/2017 and my data looks like:

```
ItemCode     Date  
1            6/1/2017  
1            6/7/2017  
1            6/10/2017  
2            6/2/2017  
2            6/8/2017  
2            6/15/2017
```

I would want the result to be

```
ItemCode     Date  
1            6/7/2017  
2            6/8/2017
```

My query so far is:

```
SELECT PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.ItemCode, Min(PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.RequiredDate) AS NextPO
FROM PO_PurchaseOrderDetail
GROUP BY PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.ItemCode
HAVING (((Min(PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.RequiredDate))>=Now()));
```

The problem is that the Min function fires first and grabs the earliest dates per ItemCode, which are before today.  Then the >=Now() is evaluated and because the min dates are before today, the query returns nothing.

I've tried putting the >=Now() inside the min function in the HAVING part of the query but it does not change the result.

My structure is wrong and I would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach like this for standard SQL, Access approach may vary

```
select PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.ItemCode,
       min(PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.RequiredDate) as NextPO

from PO_PurchaseOrderDetail
where PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.RequiredDate >= Now()
group by PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.ItemCode;
```

Comment: Perfect.  Also, it works just fine in Access.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Put the date condition in the *`where`* clause (not the `having` clause):

```
select ItemCode, min(Date) as NextPO
from PO_PurchaseOrderDetail
where Date > '6/6/2017'
group by ItemCode
```

Comment: Both this and JohnHC's answer work very well. Thank you!